# How to fix the Android studios project file layout

Tags: android, project

Typically when I use Android studios the project files on the side bar are all nice, organized and clean; having App - (manifest, java, res, assets) Gradle Scripts -

I like when it is like that. But for some reason, every so often when I open a project, typically one that I did on another computer with Android Studios, the files come in all expanded, That is they look like they just came out of the folder looking something like this: .gradle- .idea- app -(build, libs, src, .gitIgnore, app.iml, build.gradle, progaurd-rules.pro) build- gradle- And Still more. It is messy any unorganized. Even more, my namespaces are all expanded, so when I view files I have to expand the folders way out. 
Android studios when working the way I like puts the namespaces into one folder, that is there will be a folder that is called com.etc.whatever and it doesn't have to be expanded way out.

So how do I get it back to normal?

Comment: What project perspective your are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change your project structure to Packages. it may work.
explore the other option given in project structure.

Comment: I noticed that closing the project and then reopening it by only clicking on the app_name folder seems to fix it. Just have to make sure the folder is selected and not some arbitrary file inside the folder.